# Avoid hard-coded roles in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, roles

I understand that in mvc to implement role based security at the controller or action level for my site I could paint the class or method with something like the following:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "DOMAIN\GROUPNAME")]
```

(I use windows authentication)

Previously in asp.net I might have done this with a location section in the config.

The problem I have with doing this is that this site is installed in various environments in the company and for each environment that value could be different.

Is there a way to give these roles an alias with a mapping in the config? Or have I got something wrong here?

**EDIT**

I tried:

```
[Authorize(Roles=ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["UpdateRole"])]
```

But this gives me the error: "An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this:
[ASP.NET MVC - Dynamic Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397923/asp-net-mvc-dynamic-authorization)